# How to visually identify a rap hanger?

Tags: gear, safety, rock-climbing

If I'm out on the rock and I come across a pair of hangers, how can I tell the difference between [rap hangers](http://www.metoliusclimbing.com/bolt_hangers.html) (the kind you can directly thread rope through to rappel) and regular hangers (the kind that you must clip a carabiner or quick link into)? I would be specifically looking for the rap hangers since without identification they could both be used like regular hangers.

[image]

Comment: The one pictured is not suitable rap anchor.

Comment: @mattnz I pulled it from a [metolius rap hanger product page](http://www.backcountrygear.com/metolius-rap-hangers.html)

Comment: Sorry - in  the image it does not look suitable as it appears to have a sharp edge, but the blurb says its radiused and suitable for rap/belay.

Comment: I think there is a huge difference between active abseiling, were the rope is not running through the anchor during the abseiling process, and a passive descending of the climber by the belayer. In the latter case, I would be careful with a so-called rap hanger as you pictured it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't rappel directly off a hanger if any of these is true:

- The rope does not easily fit through the hole (with room to spare)
- The hole's edges are not smoothly rounded
- The material that forms the hole is much thinner than a carabiner

Because all of these increase the change the rope will get stuck or damaged.

Comment: you should also check the hanger for wear. Many rap hangers become badly worn and can cut a rope or break when weighted